# margin between two display table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS

```css
#one,
#two {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 47px;
  background: red;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A4we7/1/)

But couldn't achieve as my desired. I need space between two divs. If I give padding value it will give space but do not remove the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `border-spacing` and `border-collapse` rules on the *parent* div, not the `table-cell` divs.

Comment: I have faced another problem: I don't need margin-bottom

Comment: You can change the vertical margin my adding an other value to border-spacing. `border-spacing: 10px 0;` (http://jsfiddle.net/A4we7/7/)

Comment: Oh! I was using `0 10px` but how does this work `10px 0` top and right in other but here is opposite. I'm confused.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp if two value the first set the horizontal spacing and the second the vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Change `display: table-cell;` to `display: inline-table;` or `display: inline;`
I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/WNKCZ/1/

```
#main
{
    border-spacing:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "border-spacing" in the parent div

```
<div style="border-spacing: 10px;">
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following property :

```
<div style="border-spacing: 10px;">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</idv>
</div>
```

Or use following css style :

```
#one, #two{
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    height: 47px; 
    background: red;
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your css code as below :

```
#one, #two{
    display: inline; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    height: 47px; 
    background: red;
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

i changed **display** property **table-cell** to **inline**. you can also use  **inline-table**

next you can use **margin** property to make space between two block(i.e. margin-left:20px;).